# Problem with string methods in asp.net views

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, asp.net-mvc-5

I have info with drives names in array of string with next string format - "C:\" , "D:\". I trying to pass drive name to the controller but receive error because of ':' symbol. So i decide to delete symbol ':' from the each string in the array to pass only drive letter, like 'C' or 'D'.

I've tried to use `Trim` but it doesn't work `Replace` and `Substring` too.

```cs
@{ //doesn't work, myString will not change

    string str = "std";
    str.Trim('d');
    str.Substring(1);
    str.Replace('d', 'q');
    @str; // str == "std"

string myString = Model.Content_array[i,0].Trim({ new char[] {':'} );
   string myString2 = Model.Content_array[i, 0].Substring(0, Model.Content_array[i, 0].Length - 2)

@Html.ActionLink((string)Model.Content_array[i, j], "Index", new { id = myString ) })
}

// but this code works
@Html.ActionLink((string)Model.Content_array[i, j], "Index", new { id = Model.Content_array[i, 0].Substring(0, Model.Content_array[i, 0].Length -2) })
```

Why string methods doesn't work with the string but it works in the ActionLink method?

Comment: Are you confusing `Trim` with `Replace` ?

Comment: Absolutely as @PanagiotisKanavos said. You array element doestn't ends with `:` though

Comment: `Trim` simply removes whitespace, it does not remove or replace any other characters. I would suggest, if you really need to extract the single letter, using a regular expression to match only the letter portion: `[a-zA-Z]` or `[\u\l]`.

Comment: @gmiley that's not true *Trim simply removes whitespace, it does not remove or replace any other characters* see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
All string methods (Trim, Replace, Substring) does not change the string. 
`
@{
    string str = "std";
    str.Trim('d');
    str.Substring(1);
    str.Replace('d', 'q');
    @str; // str == "std"
} `

Comment: @Rahul Thanks captain pedantic, I was in a bit of a rush and didn't see that the parameter version of `Trim(char[])` was used, so I was referring to the zero parameter `Trim()`. Regardless, the comment I made was more about using a regular expression to match the desired character to extract. So I humbly apologize for my mistake. Please forgive me...

Comment: @gmiley nothing to be sorry of ... just thought of sharing and I got your point too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable - they do not change the string in place.  You can use:

```
str = str.Trim('d');
```

or any of the other variants you've tried.